# Defined bash commands not found when passed in "do shell script" in osascript

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, script

I am new to shell script and recently wrote a script to open a new terminal window and run defined functions via osascript with "do shell script", but the result showed the command not found. My script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    echo "Hello World"
}

openNewWindowAndRun() {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"Terminal\"
            activate        
            do script \"$1\"
        end tell
    "
}

openNewWindowAndRun hello
```

I have also tried to directly call the `hello` function in the `openNewWindowAndRun` but didn't get any luck:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    echo "Hello World"
}

openNewWindowAndRun() {
    osascript -e "
        tell application \"Terminal\"
            activate        
            do script \"hello\"
        end tell
    "
}

openNewWindowAndRun
```

When I ran the script, it opened the new window successfully but showed the error message:
[image]

Does anyone know which part I missed here? Is it possible to pass a defined function as a parameter to osascript? If anyone can give me a hand,  that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello` is a function defined within a shell script, it can only be called by bash code from within the script itself. It is not accessible directly from the command line (your screen shot) nor from within Applescript (your `osascript` call).

To resolve this, you need to turn your `hello` function into a shell script itself.

Comment: Thank for the explanation! It makes sense. Could you point me to how to turn the `hello` function into a shell script? I just tried to convert it to a script with `export -f hello` in `/usr/local/bin` and then ran my original script again, but it still showed the same error. I have checked `which hello` but it didn't show anything. Does that mean the exporting was incorrect and not working?

Comment: It's working now. I copied and pasted `echo "Hello World"` into a new script file, put it under `/usr/local/bin`, ran `source ~/.bash_prrofile` in the terminal, set the permission for the script and ran `hello`. Thanks you @nohillside